# Как настроить расширение "x86 and x86_64 Assembly" для VS Code

Tags: ассемблер, visual-studio-code, assembly, visual-studio-extensions

Никаких инструкций в описании расширения нет. В **RUNTIME_STATUS** надпись `"no status available"`. Подсветки кода, как показано в примерах тоже нет. Настроек расширение не предоставляет. У меня Windows. (переменная с путём к **NASM** в **PATH** есть)

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, там нет никаких настроек, кроме автозакрытия скобок и комментария. По сути расширение предоставляет только подсветку синтаксиса. Подсветка должна включаться при выборе языкового режима `x86 and x86_64 Assembly` в панели статуса (должно само выбираться при открытии asm файлов).

Comment: Подскажите, где выбирать языковой режим, и в какой панели статуса?

Comment: Панель статуса, он же status bar - информационная полоска в самом низу окна: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MsgmN.png